# Overflow and Invalid Values encountered in double scalars - Nonlinear PDE Solving

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numerical-methods, pde

I am seeking to find a finite difference solution to the 1D Nonlinear PDE

u_t = u_xx + u(u_x)^2

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import math

''' 
We explore three different numerical methods for solving the PDE, with solution u(x, t),

u_t = u_xx + u(u_x)^2 

for (x, t) in (0, 1) . (0, 1/5)
u(x, 0) = 40 * x^2 * (1 - x) / 3
u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0

'''
M = 30
dx = 1 / M
r = 0.25
dt = r * dx**2
N = math.floor(0.2 / dt)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, M + 1)
t = np.linspace(0, 0.2, N + 1)

U = np.zeros((M + 1, N + 1))                      # Initial array for solution u(x, t)

U[:, 0] = 40 * x**2 * (1 - x) / 3                 # Initial condition (: for the whole of that array)
U[0, :] = 0                                       # Boundary condition at x = 0
U[-1, :] = 0                                      # Boundary condition at x = 1 (-1 means end of the array)




'''
Explicit Scheme - Simple Forward Difference Scheme
'''

for q in range(0, N - 1):
    for p in range(0, M - 1):
        b = 1 / (1 - 2 * r)
        C = r * U[p, q] * (U[p + 1, q] - U[p, q])**2
        U[p, q + 1] = b * (U[p, q] + r * (U[p + 1, q + 1] + U[p - 1, q + 1]) - C)


T, X = np.meshgrid(t, x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(T, X, U)
#fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5) # colour bar for reference

ax.set_xlabel('t')
ax.set_ylabel('x')
ax.set_zlabel('u(x, t)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('FDExplSol.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

The code I use produces the following error:

```
overflow encountered in double_scalars
  C = r * U[p, q] * (U[p + 1, q] - U[p, q])**2

invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  U[p, q + 1] = b * (U[p, q] + r * (U[p + 1, q + 1] + U[p - 1, q + 1]) - C)

invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  C = r * U[p, q] * (U[p + 1, q] - U[p, q])**2

Z contains NaN values. This may result in rendering artifacts.
  surf = ax.plot_surface(T, X, U)
```

I've looked up these errors and I assume that the square term generates values too small for the dtype. However when I try changing the dtype to account for a larger range of numbers (`np.complex128`) I get the same error.

The resulting plot obviously has most of its contents missing. So, my question is, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Discretisation expression was incorrect.

Should be

```
for q in range(0, N - 1):
    for p in range(0, M - 1):
        U[p, q + 1] = r * (U[p + 1, q] - 2 * U[p, q] + U[p - 1, q]) + r * U[p, q] * (U[p + 1, q] - U[p, q])
```